# JQuery .css() returning 100% as 100px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<style>
.info{
        width:94%;
      }
</style>
```

Now doing like this using JQuery

```
$('.info').css('width');
```

returns **94px** rather than the equivalent value in pixles (**500px** in my case.)

if i set the width in css as **105%** , JQuery would return it as **105px** .

The height and width of the parent container is 600px and 500px respectively.

Comment: This only means that its parent has a width of 100px exactly.

Comment: @DanielA.White  i tried JQuery 1.7 as well as the latest 1.8

Comment: @BramVanroy The height of the container is 600px

Comment: .css('width') will always return the width in pixels even if you give the width in % in its css file.
the % you give in css is compared with its parent element.there is something wrong with your code.put your code in fiddle.

Comment: the height? You want the width maybe.

Comment: @jose:thats the place where he might have got wrong.
mevin check the height and width both.it seems that width=100px from result what you are getting.

Comment: The height and width of the parent container is 600px and 500px respectively. @MilindAnantwar

Comment: @mevin:thats weird.put your code somewhere.

Comment: This can happen when there are more than one element on the page with the class `info`. Have tried to put an explanation in my asnwer

Comment: BTW 94% of 600px is 564px and not 500px

Comment: This is still a bug as of jQuery 2.1.4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think a possible cause is the container of the element being hidden at the moment you're trying to obtain the dimensions.

I had a similar situation with nested divs and tables.

See the following fiddle where I managed to reproduce the behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/36yvb/

I still think it's a bug in jQuery returning a percentage as an integer number (without the `%` sign) when not being able to actually compute the dimensions of the element.
Change the width of `#another-cell` (expressed in %) and see it return the same value without the `%` sign when the table is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it doesn't seem so: [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QreBa/6/).

html:

```
<div id="info"></div>
```

css:

```
html, body {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}

#info {        
    width: 94%;
}
```

js:

```
$( function() {
    document.write( $('#info').css('width') );
});
```

what is info width relative to? is it an element with 100px width maybe?

Comment: The width of the parent of info is 500px .

Comment: It doesn't matter the width of the parent. What you want to check is the width of the closest ancestor with the attribute position set to relative or absolute. Could be the parent or a more distant ancestor.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding how you are getting the value you are seeing. jQuery should return the correct width, as long as you are querying for it in the correct manner. I put together this simple fiddle using jQuery 1.7.2 http://jsfiddle.net/2jPK9/1/. Like Jose Faeti said, make sure you are taking into consideration other elements. Something else could be constricting its width.

Answer (score 0):

The width that it returns depends upon what part of the HTML is it written in. Meaning to say is that if it is written inside  tag then then 94% percent would reflect 94% of that particular div.

But again if another tag in the same  tag is already using some amount of defined width then the info might even get lesser space if the tag in defined before the info tag.

Please give up more amount of actual code to get a better answer

Comment: yes its suppose the return 94% of that div(parent div) but unfortunately its returning 94px rather than something around 490px @CJ

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that explains this behavior is that you have more than one element with the class `info`

When this happens and you do a `$('.info').css('width');` jQuery will return to you the `width` of the first element in the set.

If this is the case, you may need to be more specific with your selector.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e9Ytg/1/)

Comment: There's only one div with info class in the web page . The problem is the .css('width') in my case is returning the same value i set in the style sheet as a px . If i set the width as 200% , the .css('width') returns 200px .Its like its removing the % and adding px to the value @clyde

Comment: You may have to post your code. Else it might be hard/impossible to explain why this is happening.

Answer (score -1):

Each broswer will return textually different, but logically equal values e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255) when using .css()

Instead of using `.css('width')` use `.width()`

According to jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/width/

> The difference between .css(width) and .width() is that the latter
>   returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former
>   returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The .width()
>   method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a
>   mathematical calculation.

Comment: .width() also returns % as px